# Iterating Populated List<> Using Enhanced For Loop, temporary variable not populating

Tags: java, iteration

Syntax reference:

```
for (typeName tempVariable : collection) { }
```

I have a populated `collection`. Specifically an ArrayList. The list has one element. While debugging, the value of `tempVariable` is not populated.

```
List<Foo> fooList = methodWhichPopulatesFooList(); // works fine, returns ArrayList<Foo>

if (fooList != null) // evaluates to true
{
  for (Foo tempFoo : fooList )
    {
       // tempFoo evaluates to null; // What am I missing?
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there any circumstance in which this could occur?

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: You are mixing the list itself, and values contained in the list.

Comment: You should take a closer look at what is happening in `methodWhichPopulatesFooList()` -- it is probably inserting `null` values into the list it returns.

Comment: Foo object wraps five other objects. Three of these objects are null, two of them are populated. Such an object should != null, correct?

Answer (score 4):

The only reason why this could happen is that `methodWhichPopulatesFooList` returns a non-empty `List<Foo>` that contains one or more `null` items.

There are two ways to deal with this problem:

- If `methodWhichPopulatesFooList` should return a list of only non-null `Foo`s, fix the method to stop returning lists with `null` elements
- If `methodWhichPopulatesFooList` is allowed to return lists with some or all `Foo`s set to `null`, add a check to your `for` loop to eliminate `null`s.

Comment: +1. As with rgettman's comments, your input is accurate and helpful, but checking into it didn't resolve my problem. Going to try a different IDE and see how it goes!

Answer (score 4):

`List`s generally allow `null` as an element, so `methodWhichPopulatesFooList` must be inserting at least one `null` into the `List` that it returns.  You'll have to check `tempFoo` for being `null` or change `methodWhichPopulatesFooList` not to insert a `null` into the `List`.

Comment: +1 All valid points. Plenty of room for introduction of a null element, but a thorough check eliminated these possibilities within my code. Much thanks for your accurate input :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to check if it's `null`

```
Foo[] foo = {null};
List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(foo); // works fine, returns ArrayList<Foo>

for (Foo tempFoo : fooList) {
    System.out.println("temFoo: "+tempFoo);
    if (tempFoo == null) continue; // What are you missing.
    System.out.println("tempFoo is not null here!");
}
```

Comment: That's implicit if the iteration even begins... isn't it? :)

Comment: The iteration begins and it's printing `temFoo: null` on the console.

Comment: Yep, you're correct - while I was incorrect in assuming the for loop wouldn't iterate over a null element. Thanks for clarifying the basics on that one. However, when I implement the null check within the scope of the for loop I encounter the same results in the debugger. My ArrayList is populated with one non-null element but my temporary variable is null. And, yep, that's after I step past the assignment which occurs when the for loop is initiated :) I'm going to try a different IDE, I don't have any other ideas what would cause this. Thank you *VERY* much for your input!

Comment: If your temporary variable is `null` you can't use it as object reference, so you can skip it in the code block where it lives. Repopulating a list with non-null elements requires a time as twice as passing a loop. It's not much efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can add null element also in the `Arraylist` in which case your `ArrayList` size will increase by one.TO check the size of your List,you should use `fooList.size()` or `fooList.isEmpty()` to check whether it is empty or not

Comment: Testing those conditions resulted in --> 1  /  false.